# Ionic Side menu scroll not working in android 4.4.4

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have been struggling to overcome this problem.Any help appreciated.

I have a side-menu which is now allowing me to scroll down on android v4.4.4
Tried different solutions given on internet but in vain.
here is my code.

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false" ng-controller="SideMenuController">
<ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-content"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-content>      
           some list and content
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Simple code it is. But am not able to figure out a way to make it work in android v4.4.4.
Any hack to make it work ??

EDIT : I use ionic 1.7.16

Comment: connect ur device to the system..and debug through chrome://inspect

Comment: Tested . Debugged. I can find nothing wrong there. Its working even in 4.4.2. But not working in 4.4.4 only

Comment: Don't see any reason for this..i have scrollable side menu in my ionic app..it works on android 4..i don't know if its 4.4.4..check my app here at i.diawi.com/aSnewH ...it uses latest ionic.. see and compare them..good luck

Comment: I just checked my app on 4.4.4.. It's working fine